# Who was the first ordained rabbi to live in the USA?

Tags: rabbis, history

Who was the first ordained rabbi to live in the USA? What was his position?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Depends on what you mean by "live in." Rabbi Rice was indeed the first one to move to the US as a permanent resident, but earlier there was [Rabbi Raphael Chaim Yitzchak Karigal of Hebron](https://web.archive.org/web/20100228180702/http://www.tzemachdovid.org/gedolim/jo/tpersonality/rkarigal.html), who spent some time in the (future) United States in 1773, and served during this time as the unofficial rav of Newport, RI.

Answer (score 10):

> In 1840 the first ordained rabbi
>   arrived in the United States. His name
>   was Rabbi Abraham Rice, and he assumed
>   the position as Rov of Congregation
>   Nidchei Yisroel of Baltimore.

http://www.oukosher.org/index.php/articles/single_print/103

http://www.jewishpress.com/pageroute.do/41340/

Comment: Baltimore's Shearith Israel Congregation ("The Glen Avenue Shul", a.k.a. Rabbi Yaakov Hopfer's shul) traces its succession of rabbis all the way to Rabbi Rice.